# Why is it impossible to inject generic classes?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a generic abstract template class. I thought if I create type-specific Producers, I could inject some DAO service directly in the generic class. But I can't.

Why? And how could I work around this?

```
abstract class MyView<T> {
    @Inject
    MyDao<T> dao;

    //some more template methods that make use of the dao
    void someMethod() {
        dao.use();
    }
}

class CustomerView extends MyView<Customer> {
    //javax.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException: Ambigious resolution
}


class DaoManager {
    @Produces
    MyDao<Customer> getDaoCustomer() {
        return DaoFactory.make(Customer.class);
    }

    @Produces
    MyDao<Product> getDaoProduct() {
        return DaoFactory.make(Product.class);
    }
}
```

When I inject eg a `@Inject MyDao<Customer> dao;` it works perfectly. But not with generics...

Comment: How is your `DaoFactory` implemented?

Comment: Please define "does not work". Also, how is `@Inject MyDao<Customer> dao;` not generic?

Comment: Does not work means throws an exception. Of course MyDao<Customer> is generic to a certain degree. Still I'd like to inject a fully generic doa to the abstract method. Not a customised one.

Comment: Dao is in my case, as I use Vaadin, a sort of: `JPAContainerFactory.make(class)`

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you request

```
@Inject MyDao<Customer> dao;
```

the container knows that you want a bean specifically of type `MyDao<Customer>`. If such a bean exists and its type information is known, then the container can satisfy the injection. For example, the type information is preserved in your `@Produces` annotated method

```
@Produces
MyDao<Product> getDaoProduct() {
```

The container uses reflection to retrieve that parameterized type and can match it to the requested `@Inject` field.

With

```
abstract class MyView<T> {
    @Inject
    MyDao<T> dao;
```

however, all the container knows is that you want a `MyDao`. `T` is a type variable, not a concrete parameterization. The container cannot assume a specific type for it. In your case, both of the `@Produces` beans would match and there would be ambiguity.

---

In your example, we know from the context that it really wants a `MyDao<Customer>`. That doesn't seem to be something your container is capable of doing, ie. trying to resolve the type parameter to a concrete type argument for a parameterized subclass.