# Generics and Dependency Injection in Java

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection

I am developing a Java EE application that uses JAX-RS for the WebLayer.

I tried to break down the problem. So the code you’ll see is just a cutout. For now everything works fine. As you can see I have an `UserEndpoint` where a client can create a new user. After everything is done a verification mail is sent by the `VerificationService`.

**UserEndpoint**

```
@Path("/users")
@Stateless
public class UserEndpoint {

    @Inject
    @AuthenticatedUser
    private User authenticatedUser;

    @EJB
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @EJB
    private TokenDAO tokenDAO;

    @Inject
    private PasswordValidator passwordValidator;

    @Inject
    private UserValidator validator;

    @Inject
    private VerificationService verificationService;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User createUser(User user) {

        // Validation and Creation

        // Verification
        this.verificationService.sendVerificationMail(user);

        return user;
    }
}
```

**VerificationService**

```
@Singleton
public class VerificationService {

    @Inject
    private MailService mailSender;

    @Inject
    private TemplateService templateService;

    public void sendVerificationMail(User user) {
        this.templateService.setUserTemplate(TemplateCategory.VerificationTemplate, user);
        mailSender.sendMail(new Message(
            MessageDAO.systemEmailAddresses.get(0),
            user.getEmail(),
            templateService.getSubject(),
            templateService.getContent()));
    }
}
```

Because I want to have a scalable project I decided to encapsulate parts of the endpoint, so I can make use of it in other projects. Since every user has to be verified in one way or another I thought that the encapsulation of the verification process would be a good idea. The problem is that I have no clue how to realize that. My first approach was as followed:

**CoreUserEndpoint**

```
@Path("/users")
@Stateless
public abstract class CoreUserEndpoint<D extends BaseUserDAO<T>, T extends BaseUser, V extends CoreUserValidator<D, T>> extends EntityEndpoint<D, T, V> {

    @EJB
    private TokenDAO tokenDAO;

    @Inject
    private PasswordValidator passwordValidator;

    @Inject
    private VerificationService<T> verificationService;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User createUser(User user) {

        // Validation and Creation

        // Verification
        this.verificationService.sendVerificationMail(user);

        return user;
    }
}
```

**EntityEndpoint**

```
@Stateless
public class EntityEndpoint<D extends CoreDAO<T>, T extends CoreEntity, V extends CoreValidator> {

    protected D entityDAO;

    @Inject
    @AuthenticatedUser
    protected T authenticatedUser;

    protected V entityValidator;

}
```

**VerificationService**

```
@Singleton
public class VerificationService<T extends BaseUser> {

    @Inject
    private MailService mailSender;

    @Inject
    private TemplateService<T> templateService;

    public void sendVerificationMail(User user) {
        this.templateService.setUserTemplate(TemplateCategory.VerificationTemplate, user);
        mailSender.sendMail(new Message(
            MessageDAO.systemEmailAddresses.get(0),
            user.getEmail(),
            templateService.getSubject(),
            templateService.getContent()));
    }
}
```

When I tried this I get the famous `WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies` error. And I think I do understand why this is happening. As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234733/why-is-it-impossible-to-inject-generic-classes) I cannot make use of generics, neither for `@Inject` nor for `@EJB`. But if I am not able to use generics how can I encapsulate the core of my project? Is their any work around or a different approach? I am sure there already is a solution for that anywhere in the internet. But after 3 days of searching without making any progress I get really frustrated and thought It would be best to ask you guys. So I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to understand the logic. Since my comments with questions are too long, I decided to post here in aswer section.

Disclaimer: *It doesn't answer you question directly*

So, let's start:

> A generic class is defined with the following format:
>
> `class name<T1, T2, ..., Tn> { /* ... */ }` The type parameter section,
>   delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows the class name. It specifies
>   the type parameters (also called type variables) `T1, T2, ..., and Tn`.

**1.** So by doing this:

```
public abstract class CoreUserEndpoint<D extends BaseUserDAO<T>, T extends BaseUser, V extends CoreUserValidator<D, T>>
```

the type variables `D extends BaseUserDAO<T>, T extends BaseUser, V extends CoreUserValidator<D, T>`, instruct Java compiler that in order to use `CoreUserEndpoint` one needs to specify the types.

**2.** Next when you do this:

```
public abstract class CoreUserEndpoint<...> extends EntityEndpoint<D, T, V>
```

you use the previously defined type arguments to be used in `EntityEndpoint`. Now, compiler would look for classes (or interfaces, ...) named `D`, `T` and `V`.

Here comes the part which I am not sure about. If compiler finds them from your declaration for `CoreUserEndpoint`, then you're trying to force the class to extend from multiple classes, which is not allowed, by doing this:

```
public class EntityEndpoint<D extends CoreDAO<T>, T extends CoreEntity, V extends CoreValidator>
```

*P.S. I would higly appreciate any feedback, if what I've written here makes any sence, from experience Java devs.*

Comment: I think that `public class EntityEndpoint<D extends CoreDAO<T>, T extends CoreEntity, V extends CoreValidator>` shouldn't cause any errors. In fact if I do `TemplateService<User>` instead of `TemplateService<T>` within `VerificationService` and leave the code as it is I get no Exceptions. But I cannot explain this statement from a technical point of view.

Comment: If you have a public repo for your project, I wouldn't mind to clone it and wonder around it :) I might get better insight of your problem